# Rails: does before action in module overwrite the one in the class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a controller with a `skip_before_action`:

```
class UsersController 
 skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: :create

 include Confirmable

 def create
   # ...
 end

end
```

and a `Confirmable` module:

```
module Confirmable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: :confirm_email
  end

  def confirm_email
    # ...
  end
end
```

Does the `skip_before_action` in the module overwrite the one in the class or add to it i.e. creating `skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:create, :confirm_email]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Rails* is *OSS*.

Here is the implementation of [`skip_before_action`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L211-L217).

Callbacks are implemented as a [collection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cba70a86da60a14aeca80f3c49d5d868d2db0520/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L94).

Unless [`prepend: true`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cba70a86da60a14aeca80f3c49d5d868d2db0520/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L680) option is explicitly passed, newly defined callbacks are *appended* to the list of existing callbacks. That said, both would take place.

Also, `self#included` callback is called as it’s found in the source code, hence module one is *appended* to the *class* one.